# magento Qquoteadv Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block_Toolbar error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

there is a module for Magento by Ophirah called Qquoteadv and I think it's by https://www.cart2quote.com

I have found a log exception.log which reports this:
`
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block_Toolbar' in /chroot/home/mysite.com/html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:

## 0 /chroot/home/mysite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')

`

Could anyone please give me a clue on why is this probably happening?
I 'd never address to this issue if the cart page would work but with this module XML enable the Cart Page crashed

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: hi there thanks for your vote: it's a bad integration so that block is not found